# How to fake the type in JSON.NET when serializing out?

Tags: c#, json.net

lets say I have

```
public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

now, if I create an anonymous type like...

```
var p = new Person() {FirstName = "bob",
                      LastName = "builder",
                      PhoneNumber = "0800 YESWECAN"};

var anon = new {p.FirstName, p.LastName};
```

with JSON.NET, when you have TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,  it will serialize ( and then use for deserilization ) the type.    What I'm wanting to do, is to fake the type in the annoymous class so that when it gets serialized it looks like a "Person" object.

Is there a nice simple way to do this?

NOTE:  It MUST have the Json.Net type information in the json  ( $type ).  So LBs answer doesn't solve the problem, in fact I could just use the .net frameworks json facilities to do exactly that.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't use `new Person { FirstName = "", LastName = "" }`?

Comment: yes......  that would still have an object with "PhoneNumber".   For this instance, I don't want phone number serialized  (  it's a contrived example to ask the question, in reality, the object models are complex ).  I updated the example to try and make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to fake it, I can introduce a contract to change a property name when outputting the json...  eg...

```
 public class FakeTypeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {        
        protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            return propertyName == "_type_" ? "$type" : propertyName;
        }
    }
```

so if you have json.net deserializer settings set to

```
TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
```

you can make an annoymous type like the following,

```
var x = new 
{
     _type_ = typeof(Person).AssemblyQualifiedName,
     p.FirstName, 
     p.LastName
}
```

Which will pretend to be a "Person" in the type information,  meaning if you deserialize it you will get a person object.

NOTE: the serializer to json settings must be set not to serialize out type information when you are faking it.

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize as

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { FirstName = "aaa", LastName = "bbb" })
```

and you will get a string which looks like Person object

```
{"FirstName":"aaa","LastName":"bbb"}
```

Since Json doesn't contain type informations you can deserialize it back to Person

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, typeof(Person));
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the right answer. I think the OP needs the object serialized with the `$type` set to `Person` so that it can be deserialized later without having to know the object type.

Comment: `I don't believe this is the right answer` , `this isn't the right answer` @KeithNicholas @CAbbott  What is wrong with it? What do you really expect?  Justify your answers

Comment: because when the object model is more complex, you need the type information  ( especially with sublassing ).  My question is about how to FAKE the type information with anonymous types.

Comment: `because when the object model is more complex, you need the type information` is not an answer. You may not need it. Just ask your real problem and get a solution to it. It think this some kind of XY problem http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Comment: From the Json.NET documentation: *TypeNameHandling controls whether Json.NET includes .NET type names during serialization with a **$type property and reads .NET type names from that property to determine what type to create during deserialization**.*

Comment: You can deserialize a Json string to any object you want as in my answer. Your problem is something different, you think it can be solved with this type info and you ask this. But what I say is your problem can be handled in a different (and maybe more correct) way

Comment: LB, my real problem is to do with how to efficiently serialize json models through to a web page which knockousjs then uses to create a view model.   Part of the object structure is various objects in collections that are subclasses.   In order to do that, you need type information in the json to know what type of objects you have when deserializing.   The anonymous types allow you to efficiently create filtered json vms from your entities. But when deserializing they need to map to the orginals

Comment: I don't want to continue this discussion anymore, but what I want to say lastly is, A few yers ago, I created a framework similar to WCF(ofcourse only a limited subset of it) based on Json-RPC using Json.Net and I never required type info. Just pure Jsons travelled on the network as in my answer.

Comment: imagine a if person had a List<IToy>  Toys......  and then had various objects like Boat, Car, BuzzLightYear in that collection.   Having the type information allows you to recreate that list.

Comment: Keith's use case is fairly common, and there are legitimate cases where going from a typeless serialization format like JSON into a typed environment like .NET requires the original type to ensure correctness.